# AWS Elasticache Redis on ready code is not executing in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

Here is the lambda I wrote

```
"use strict";

const redis = require('redis');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const client = redis.createClient({url: 'redis://anaha-redis.something.so.0001.meth.ing.amazonaws.com:6379'});

    client.on("error", (err) => {
        client.quit();
        console.log("Redis encountered an error.");
        callback(err, null);
    });
    
    client.on("ready", () => {
        const data = { type: "helloWorld", data: "Hello World!" };
        client.publish("testLambda-get-test-helloWorld", JSON.stringify(data));
        client.quit();
        console.log("HELLLLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO",data);
        return data;
    });
};
```

But the the code inside on ready is not being executed. Because Cloud Watch Logs is not showing HELLLLLOOOOOOOOOOOOOO as I have logged in that part of code.

What am I doing wrong? What is a better approach?